# How to change title bar background color of Dojox.layout.FloatingPane

Tags: dojo

The appearance (background color) of my Floating Pane's title bar and its main pane are the same.  How can I make the background color of the title bar different?

```
<div id="fltQury" class="roundedCorners" data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.FloatingPane" 
  title="A Floating Pane" dockable="false" closable="true"
  style="width: 350px; height: 100px; top: 100px; left: 120px; " >
<div>
```

Thanks,
Gido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use CSS to do that, for example:

```css
#fltQury .dojoxFloatingPaneTitle {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This should be working fine, as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqP6B/

Comment: That was so simple; but that's exactly what I needed.  Thanks so much,

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the CSS may change all the styles pertaining to dojoxFlotingPaneTitle. Rather, I would suggest to use the following dojo.style to change the color.

```
var resultDiv = dojo.byId('fltQury');    
dojo.style(resultDiv, {
       "backgroundColor": "#a4e672",
       "color": "black"
   });
```

for more information, please go through the [this link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/isObject.html).

Comment: This will change the background ot he entire floating pane, not only the title. Could you also explain in why you would use this in stead of using a CSS selector like `#fltQury .dojoxFloatingPaneTitle`? In the end it does the exact same thing.

Comment: I don't recommend this approach tbh, relying on the fact that the widget will be parsed into a DOM node with the same ID is not a good thing. Rather use `dijit.byId('fltQury').domNode in stead of `dojo.byId()`.

Comment: `#fltQury .dojoxFloatingPaneTitle` will add the style to all floating panes. If the requirement is only to have a specific style for only one floating pane then `#fltQury .dojoxFloatingPaneTitle` may not holds good. @DimitriM, I agree to your second point. using dojo.byId() would be expensive operation. We would better use dijit.byId().

Comment: `#fltQury .dojoxFloatingPaneTitle` only adds the style to the floating pane with ID `#fltQury` (which is only 1 floating pane, since IDs are unique). Here's the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/nqP6B/1/

Comment: Sorry. I have overlooked #fltQury. you are correct.